# How to Select From List of Objects in Symfony 2 Edit Object Form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form in which you can edit the attributes of object "one".  This object has a one-to-many relationship with another object, "many".  I want a user to be able to select assign a "many" object to the "one" from the form.  I can't figure out how to do that!

Right now:

\Entity\One.php

```
class One
{
 ...
  /*
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="many", inversedBy="one")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="manyId", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $manyId;
 ...
}
```

\Controller\OneController.php

```
class OneController extends Controller
{
  ... 
    public function editAction($oneId, Request $request)
    {
        if ($oneId) {
            $one = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('One')
                ->find($oneId);
        } else {
            $one = new One();
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $manyEntity = 'Bundle\Entity\Many';
        $manyList = new EntityChoiceList($em, $manyEntity);

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($one)
            ->add('many', 'choice', array('choice_list' => $manyList))
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $entityManager->persist($one);
            }
        }
     }
 ...
}
```

This results in the error message "Expected argument of type "scalar", "Proxies\BundleEntityManyProxy" given".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved!  I should have written `->add('many', 'entity', array('class' => 'BundleMany'))`.

See http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=36604.